# I am Working on Javascript Dates, i am stuck with adding 7 days to a date

Tags: javascript, date

```
  var date = new Date();

  var first_date = new Date(date); //Make a copy of the date we want the first and last days from
  first_date.setUTCDate(1); //Set the day as the first of the month
 
  var firstDay = first_date.toJSON().substring(0, 10);  
  console.log(firstDay)
```

1. I am Working on Javascript Dates, i am stuck with adding 7 days to this date
2. Thanks in advance

Comment: Stackoverflow is here to help you with code you've written, not write it for you. Create a Date for the first of the month. *getDay* will tell you which day of the week it is. *setDate* can be used to set the date to some other day. Write some code, then post it. Others may then help you fix it.

Comment: Why don't you check momentjs, You could do much more with https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Kjjassy - There's absolutely no reason to use a library for this. This is one of the things `Date` does just fine on its own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date();

var first_date = new Date(date); //Make a copy of the date we want the first and last days from
first_date.setUTCDate(1); //Set the day as the first of the month
 
var firstDay = first_date.toJSON().substring(0, 10);

var resultDate = new Date();
resultDate.setDate(first_date.getDate() + 7);
var resultDay = resultDate.toJSON().substring(0, 10); 
console.log("First day: " + firstDay)
console.log("7 days from specific day: " + resultDay)
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't helpful. The OP is left wondering why use UTC methods? Why *toJSON* instead of *toString*? Why *substring*? Etc.